# Supervised Learning could be biased if we use obsolete data

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, supervised-learning

What if the data that we could use for the training is obsolete. For instance, if I train my model with the computer sales report from the 20th century and try to predict the actual trends, a disaster, right?

Another good example is the one that profiles criminals. It will use the historical "mistakes" as fact and could wrongly suspect innocents(based on race or ethnicity).

How could I avoid this kind of situations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach to using knowledge from the example you gave above is to use that information as a prior for your current model. While it is unlikely that the exact trends observed a while ago will predict future trends, some general observations/correlations will likely still be relevant for the present day.

Concerning your example of criminal profiling. Making predictive models in such cases can be highly biased and is controversial. I invite you to read the Outlook section XVIII.D of this ML review on the [social implications of machine learning](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.08823) and the references mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

In the case that your training data is outdated, you might have a problem if you train a model considering that dataset and then applying it at a test dataset which is newer and not outdated. In the case that you have available some new data at the training time, one solution could be to perform domain adaptation/transfer learning methods to tackle this difference e.g. in the distribution of the features taking into account the small newer dataset and the large outdated dataset. Actually you are going to find out which part of the outdated dataset remains the same or which part could be useful after some transformations. You could check the related bibliography for more information about transfer learning and domain adaptation.